# error 2006 in mysql server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

When I click on a particular portion in my website, only I found this error...  what should I do.. Please help.

Error Number: 2006

MySQL server has gone away

This is the sql query I use:

```
SELECT
    bctoad_ad.ad_title, bctoad_ad.ad_description, bctoad_ad.ad_date, bctoad_ad.ad_image,
    bctoad_pushtotop.post_rank,bctoad_pushtotop.post_id
FROM bctoad_ad
INNER JOIN bctoad_pushtotop
    ON bctoad_ad.ad_id=bctoad_pushtotop.post_id
    and bctoad_ad.ad_status='A'
    and bctoad_ad.user_id='UID130308315357256' limit 0,3`
```

Comment: Probley there is a row that is contains more than 4mb of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because of max_allowed_packet in your my.ini file on server, use this tip:
http://forums.webyog.com/index.php?showtopic=3227